# How do I prevent django from erroring out when a field doesn't exist in the schema?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I want to be able to mark a field as unused and therefore prevent django from erroring out when the corresponding column in the database schema doesn't exist.

I want to do this because there is no reason why deploying unused code should crash a site.

Something like

```
class SomeObject(Model):
  some_field = models.CharField(unused=True)

SomeObject.objects.all()[0].id  # this line should not fail
```

Right now it gives

`django.db.utils:OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'someobject.some_field' in 'field list'")`

Comment: Have you tried just excluding `some_field` from your model definition?  If it's in the schema it will just ignore it (I think).

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach is to use `try:` and `except` statements, [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). In your example,

```
try:
    SomeObject.objects.all()[0].id
exept OperationalError:
    pass # or whatever you want in this case
```

If you are using a model often, consider redefining its get_queryset function. For example,

```
class YourClass:
def get_queryset(self, request):
    try:
        super(your-model-super, self).get_queryset(request)
    exept OperationalError, error:
        if error.code == 1054:
            pass
        else:
            raise
```

I can't think of any other way to handle this.

Comment: if I was adding this field on a highly used model, say, User, I can't apply this to every bit of code that references User. I also want to throw OperationalError if it was thrown for a reason other than the unused field.

Comment: If you are using a model often, consider redefining its get_queryset function. For example,

class YourClass:
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        try:
            super(your-model-super, self).get_queryset(request)
        exept OperationalError, error:
            if error.code == 1054:
                pass
            else:
                raise

I edit my answer to show the code more clearly.